# What is the purpose of using rails' image_url helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From the docs it seems like you just save yourself from typing in the assets folder part of the image url when using this method against the vanilla url helper? What is the usefulness of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use image_url helper then rails will map the full qualified url based on the asset_host configuration. So this method gives you the freedom of just passing the name of the image as an argument and it does the rest.

Check this for more information.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html